Angular 18 SSR" ERROR RuntimeError: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'angularroute/skfnsjkdfnj.css.map'
i'm working with Angular SSR. below are the dependencies to be noted
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^18.0.2",

Node 20.14.0
npm 10.7.0
app.routes.ts

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path:"chat",component:AfterloginComponent , pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
        path:"",component: BeforeloginComponent, pathMatch: "full"
    },
    
];

    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "serve:ssr:chatapp": "node --watch dist/chatapp/server/server.mjs",

when i run the above command, and i hit http://localhost:4000/chat , below is the error i receive in the output of npm run serve:ssr:chatapp

but the contents of http://localhost:4000/chat loads fine in the browser.
in the server.ts file (auto generated by Angular SSR) , i can see below code, but i don't think the error message is thrown via the .catch(...) block
i think that, as i hit the http://localhost:4000/chat link, angular is trying to match topbar.component.css.map with the currently loaded route, but it fails to find  the file.. is this error message a problem should i try to fix?
if this is not a concern, then how to hide it, because it prints lot of messages in console and it clutters the log file.
how to fix this?




please share minimal reproducible example or a github repo, or a stackblitz with the issue happening
